# Cant execute any command on docker with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I was following [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/docker/docker_hub.htm) on tutorials point about docker, and after running ubuntu like this: `Docker run -it ubuntu bash` I tried to pull jenkins like this: `sudo docker pull jenkins` but every time I get `command not found` message, not only for this but for anything I write into docker terminal, and I did everything according to tutorial.

I am running docker on windows 7.

Comment: I think you are missing to define the path .

Comment: You must be getting the error for 'sudo'. Try without sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the tutorial you need to `docker pull jenkins` on your machine not inside the container.

When you do `docker run -it ubuntu bash` you get inside the shell of ubuntu docker container. To able to pull the jenkins image inside the container you need to have DND (docker-in-docker) where your docker socket on VM gets mounted inside the container and you can run any docker commands inside it. So if you want to run any docker commands inside container use this image https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/ or else run `docker pull jenkins` on your VM where you have docker installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try it out later.